# What is "Accrue Tax"?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

So I was looking over my paycheck, and under "Employer Paid Benefits" a little more than $100 was in the category "Accrue Tax". This did not have an affect on my income after taxes.

I've never seen that on any paycheck I've gotten.

**What is "Accrue Tax"?**

Update:
I emailed payroll and they gave me an answer

Comment: It probably means accrued tax; tax that was accrued in the previous month but wasn't paid in that month because they didn't have full tax details for you. I'm not making this an answer as 1) I'm in the UK and things may be different and 2) I'm not 100% sure as I haven't enough context

Comment: Why not just ask the Payroll Department?

Comment: @chili555 I have no clue how to reach them. I already checked the company website for contact information.

Comment: I suggest that you ask your manager or Human Resources how to contact Payroll.

Comment: You're being a bit confusing with your wording here.  "Employer paid benefits" should not include things that are "taken out of your paycheck", they should be things the employer pays for beyond your paycheck.

Comment: Does the company provide a life insurance as a benefit?

Comment: @Joe That's another reason why I'm confused, how is it a benefit to me? Is Accrue Tax a good thing?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I'm not enrolled in any benefits, I'm doing a 6 month paid college internship

Comment: You're going to have to find out what it actually is from  HR/Payroll as it's not a standard terminology.  "Employer paid benefits" simply means anything your employer pays that is considered income (or at least is sort-of-income).

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I was thinking the same, but $100 is a lot for that, I have a likely much higher company paid life insurance plan and it's far less expensive.  SPYBUG, it's possible that you have some benefits that you don't sign up for - life insurance is in fact one commonly provided; there's no cost to you, so they don't ask you.

Comment: @Joe I'm working on it, as soon as either my manager or HR responds

Comment: Actually, I wonder.  @SPYBUG96 - are there any federal tax withholding?  If not it's entirely possible your company is actually paying certain taxes for you.  It would be a weird way of going about it, but who knows.

Comment: @Joe Yeah I have all the standard taxes, Fed withholding, State withholding, etc. And since I am still in college and a dependent to my parents, I still have their life insurance. I would receive something from my company if they signed me up for life insurance, right?

Comment: I don't think that we are going to be able to answer this without more information.  What else did your second paycheck say?  What did your first paycheck say?  Do numbers add up to Accrue Tax?

Comment: @Brythan I just checked everything, and apparently "Accrue Tax" did not have an impact on my income after taxes, and I added a bit more to the question.

Comment: Well payroll got back to me. But it seems like I can't leave an answer to this question anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what my payroll department had to say:

*"It’s a percentage of employer tax the company is accruing for.  It does not affect your net."*

**Definition of "Accrue":**

(of sums of money or benefits) be received by someone in regular or increasing amounts over time.

**So it is just the employer tax my company is paying based on my salary.**